# Is there any way send the message to Cisco Jabber account by scripts?

Tags: python

My project team is using the Cisco Jabber as the instant messaging tool , and we want to send the messages automatically by the scripts in some situations.

I want to know is there any libs or code examples can do it ?

Any help is much appreciated :)

---

I tried to use the sleekxmpp lib and used the example codes in the following page :

http://sleekxmpp.com/getting_started/sendlogout.html

I replaced with my own Cisco Jabber server name in the xmpp.connect() then run :

```
python send_client.py -d -j xxxx@myserver.com -p xxxx -t xxxx@myserver.com -m "This is a message"
```

But it return the following error message , any idea? many thanks .

```
INFO     JID set to: xxxx@xxxx.com/a0d89102ee71f5a1a87c093eff5001d685a02d21
WARNING  TLS or SSL was enabled, but no certificate was found.
WARNING  Timed out waiting for IqWait_4a447480-22d9-4488-b4b8-d7a3ece5eb5b-3
ERROR    Error processing event handler: <bound method EchoBot.start of <__main__.EchoBot object at 0x02D70330>>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sleekxmpp\xmlstream\xmlstream.py", line 1699, in _event_runner
func(*args)
  File "views.py", line 66, in start
self.get_roster()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sleekxmpp\clientxmpp.py", line 258, in get_roster
response = iq.send(block, timeout, callback)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sleekxmpp\stanza\iq.py", line 233, in send
raise IqTimeout(self)sleekxmpp.exceptions.IqTimeout: <iq id="4a447480-22d9-4488-b4b8-d7a3ece5eb5b-3" type="get"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster" /></iq>

ERROR    Request timed out: <iq id="4a447480-22d9-4488-b4b8-d7a3ece5eb5b-3" type="get"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster" /></iq>
WARNING  You should catch IqTimeout exceptions
```

Comment: Hi, by any chance did you fine a solution to send messages to CISCO Jabber Chat room using Python ?